# OpenCV Crashes with Stack Overflow Or Resource Allocation Error

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I have a multithread C++ Qt program under VS2010 where one of the threads run an image processing algorithm.

I know my algorithm works because it runs fine in a console applicaiton, and I just copy and paste it in the project....then I get  all this weird errors.

The code is:

```
//...some stuff

leftMat = imread("M:/Desktop/PsEyeRight1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
cvtColor(leftMat, leftMat, CV_RGB2GRAY);       
GaussianBlur(leftMat, leftMat, Size(3, 3), 0, 0, 4);                   
threshold(leftMat, leftMat, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY); contoursLeft.clear();            
hierarchyLeft.clear();                        
Mat contourImage = leftMat.clone();           
findContours(contourImage, contoursLeft, hierarchyLeft, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));

//...some stuff
```

When the execution hits `findContours()`, I get a StackOverflow as "**Unhandled exception at 0x100a9985 (opencv_core246d.dll) in SARA.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.**"

So I to **Configuration Properties > Linker > System > Stack Reserve Size** and change it to "**100000000**" (100MB)

This time the error changes... `cvtColor()` crashes with the error "**Unhandled exception at 0x774fc41f in SARA.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Concurrency::scheduler_resource_allocation_error at memory location 0x1f63ad64..**" at concrt.h and if I remove `cvtColor()`, `Threshold()` crashes the same way.

I am compiling it as /MDd (Multi-Threaded Debug DLL) and I have also run CMake on OpenCV to clear the option "BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT", and I compiled openCV again, and the projects that I saw all had the /MDd  as well.

Does anyone has a guess about what is going on?

EDIT: 
Just to make it clear, I have enough free memory in my system to run the program.